# How to set MPU6500 to work and read the accelerometer?

Tags: arduino, hardware

I am working for a small project that I am interested in and I have been working on getting MPU6500's accelerometer's data using Arduino. However, my code just does not work. Every register that I read from wire is -1. Anyone who knows how to make it work right?

Here is my code. I am using Arduino Uno btw.

```c++
#include<Wire.h>
const int MPU_addr=0x68;  // I2C address of the MPU-6050
//Some of those boards have a pull-down resistor at AD0 (address = 0x68), others have a pull-up resistor (address = 0x69).
int16_t AcX,AcY,AcZ;

float time;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  //or one, I am not so sure 
  delay(100);
  Wire.write(0x68); 
  Wire.write(0); 
  delay(100);
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  time = micros();
}

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,6,true);  // request a total of 6 registers 

  AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)    
  AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)

  Serial.print("AcX = "); Serial.print(AcX);
  Serial.print(" | AcY = "); Serial.print(AcY);
  Serial.print(" | AcZ = "); Serial.println(AcZ);

  //delay(333);
  float temp = time - micros();
  Serial.println(temp);
  time = micros();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<Wire.h>

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(400000UL); // Set I2C frequency to 400kHz
  Wire.beginTransmission(mpu_addr);
  Wire.write(0x6B);
  Wire.write(0); // wake up the mpu6050
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {            

}

double Gyro_X()
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(mpu_addr);
  Wire.write(0x43);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(mpu_addr,2);
  double GyX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  return GyX;
}

double Acc_Y()
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(mpu_addr);
  Wire.write(0x3D);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(mpu_addr,2);
  double AccY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  return AccY;  
}

double Acc_Z()
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(mpu_addr);
  Wire.write(0x3F);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(mpu_addr,2);
  double AccZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  return AccZ;  
}
```

Comment: I used your code and added Serial.print Gyx, AccY, AccZ  in the loop, however I still only get Gyx, AccY, AccZ = -1. Any ideas of why this happened? Maybe it is the problem of I2C or MPU6500 module?

Comment: Are you on the pins are correct ?? because i work with this code, and it's fine, this is an example :  https://github.com/Touzi-Mortadha/Arduino_project/blob/master/Balancing_robot/Final_project/balancing_robot.ino

Comment: I found the problem. The pins were in the right position. However they did not connect very well and once I held it and make the connection well, it works perfectly now. Thanks!